# CN1: iOS: Showing ToastBar when virtual keyboard is visible

Tags: codenameone

On iOS (ipad pro) I cannot see the ToastBar showing messages, when the virtual keyboard is visible.
However on Android devices the ToastBar is visible in the same szenario.

Is there way to work around this or do I have to use modal dialogs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I see a problem related to that, it seems we don't handle the special case of iOS VKB's correctly.

I made a fix for this which should be there for the coming update of Codename One this weekend.